# Events between Window and CustomControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I need a suggestion of my following problem:
I have a Window with a Textbox, the CustomControl and 2 Buttons. One for saving data the user enters.

So if you look it from implementation side:

```
MyWindow : IWindow --- DataContext is ---> MyWindowModel : BaseViewModel --- contains ---> Commands : DelegateCommands

CustomControl : IControl --- DataContext is ---> CustomControlModel : BaseViewModel --- contains ---> Datagrid and SelectedItem
```

When a user changes the selection in the DataGrid of the UserControl, the property updates in the Control. So far so good, no problems here.

But the Window or to be precise the DataContext Model in a Window, checks if the User had selected something from the DataGrid and entered Data in the Textbox correctly

```
// First parameter is the Action, second is the ICommandOnCanExecute
CmdSave = new DelegateCommands(SaveAction, IsSavable);
```

The IsSavable Code:

```
public bool IsSavable(object parameter) {
    var result = Validator.Validate(this, ruleSet: "IsSavable");
    return Validator.Validate(this, ruleSet: "IsSavable").IsValid;
}
```

The validator can access the properties of the MyWindowModel for checks and the Model needs the selected item for the save action later.

Now there is no connection between the 2 Models and I don't want them to have a dependency to each other.

My solution would be, to implement an EventSystem. When the CustomControl registers the change, it will send it through the EventSystem to every subscriber and the Window just has to subscribe the CustomControl Event to his DataContext Model.

Is that ok or are there better solutions I didn´t know?

Edit:
Using Prism.Core and the Event Aggregator works like a charm. Should somebody ever be in need how to do it, use Prism.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve? Would you like for your ```Validator``` to have access to the ```SelectedItem``` to perform checks? Or do you want to call ```CmdSave``` with the ```SelectedItem``` as ```parameter```? Maybe include some more code so it's easier to follow.

Comment: The Validator should have access to the selected item without direct access to the data context of the control. My current solution is to send the item with an event to subscribers and the data context, the validator lives in, receives the object and stores it in a property. The validator has access to this data context and the property. So that is my way of decoupling without use a supervisor or singleton. More code I can provide on Monday, already left for the weekend.

Comment: You could pass the ```SelectedItem``` in the ```IsSavable``` method (which is a method of your ```MyWindowModel```?) Like this ```var result = Validator.Validate(this, ruleSet: "IsSavable", selectedItem: parameter);```? I don't know.

Comment: I upload an example later when I am back at a pc. The Validator is accessing the object via mycontext.MyObject. But with an example Project you could see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that ok or are there better solutions I didn´t know?

Yes, using an event aggregator is the way to go if you don't want any connection between the view models.

The other option would be for the views to share a common `DataContext`. `MyWindowModel` may for example expose a `CustomControlModel` property that the `CustomControl` in the window binds to.

`MyWindowModel` can then access any property of `CustomControlModel` directly while the `CustomControl` still binds to `CustomControlModel`. This does however create a dependency between `MyWindowModel` and `CustomControlModel`.

Comment: The Event Aggregator is what I wanted. Thank you.It´s the lose coupeling I´m targeting here, not using a Singleton DataContext.